# Example of e2e test using Node.js + Firebase

Tags: node.js, testing, firebase

Does there exist online a single example of proper end-to-end testing using Node.js and Firebase?

I define "proper" as:

- The tests run on a different Firebase instance than dev or prod
- The test database gets cleared before each test

Answer (score 0):

Firebase connections are persistent (i.e. once you connect, your script will run forever), so testing your Firebase code end to end is tricky.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27659502/3233631) answer adds some details there.  I've tested Firebase interactions two ways:

1. Run your app with Firebase pointing to some test references (not your production data) and write some tests against it. It's harder to follow TDD this way because you'll be writing these tests after writing your app.
2. Child processes can be useful, but are hackish (proceed with caution):

mock-user.js

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var ref = new Firebase('https://<your-app>.firebaseio.com/testUsers');

ref.set({user1: {name: 'Mike'}}, function(err){
    if (err){
        process.exit(1);
    } else{
    ref.child('user1').remove(function(err){
      if (err){
        process.exit(1);
      }
      process.exit(0);
    });
    }
});
```

test.js

```
var test = require('tape');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

test('firebase', function(t){
  t.plan(1);
  exec('node ./mock-user.js', {timeout: 5000}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
    t.ok(err === null, 'firebase user created and destroyed');
  });
});
```

This test relies on the exit code from the child process.  I don't think this would be considered a best practice, but hopefully it informs your question a bit.