# How to destroy firebase ref in node

Tags: node.js, firebase

If I do this in node:

```
console.log('1');
console.log('2');
```

outputs:

```
1
2
```

And the process ends.

If I change it to this:

```
console.log('1');
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var ref = new Firebase('https://<some-base>.firebaseio.com/');
console.log('2');
```

outputs:

```
1
2
```

and the process continues.

I believe that this is because `ref` is keeping the process alive. I know that I can use `process.exit` but I would prefer to not do that. I actually don't want the process to exit anyway, I just want to make sure that I don't have a memory leak issue where my firebase ref lasts forever. Is there any way to destroy a firebase reference once I'm done with it?

Comment: In case you come across something let me know

Comment: When you're ready to exit, just call `process.exit();`

Comment: @Kato, But I'm not ready to exit.

Answer (score 7):

[Engineer at Firebase] Currently, instantiating the Firebase client with `new Firebase(...)` will create a long-lived persistent connection that keeps the Node.js process alive.

This is admittedly not ideal for a bunch of use cases, and we have some work to do here to ensure that the process exits cleanly and automatically when there are no outstanding Firebase listeners or pending writes to the server, but it's been medium / low priority. I'd expect a "fix" to be released by Q2 '15, hopefully Q1.

Comment: Would there be a possibility for adding a method that destroys the reference explicitly? That way you don't need to worry about making sure there are no listeners or pending writes and it can be my responsibility to make sure those things are taken care of.

Comment: @kentcdodds It's possible that we would do something like this, but I imagine it would add a lot of complexity. The reference, by itself, is a small, inexpensive wrapper around the client and we'd like to keep it that way. That said, we're open to ideas on this API!

Comment: Has there been any progress on this?

Comment: @RobDiMarco So it's Q2 of '16 and this still seems to be an issue...pity.

Comment: Currently working around with `process.exit();` once I know the routine is over. If the routine is the iterated callbacks and I don't know when the "over" happens, then shifted window can be used inside the callback:
`clearTimeout(timeout);`
`timeout = setTimeout(() => {process.exit();}, 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found when using [tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) was to call `test.onFinish(() => process.exit());` at the end. It's not ideal but it seems to get the job done running it both directly and with a test runner.

Example:

```
const test = require('tape');

test('Some test', (t) => {
  // test code
});

test('Another test', (t) => {
  // test code
});

test.onFinish(() => process.exit());
```