# node.js does not terminate after object creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Simple question, very new to Node.js.

The following code does not terminate. presumably because the Firebase reference still exists?  What is happening here, and how (and should) I tell node.js that I am finished with the Firebase object so the code may stop?

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");
var ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/")
ref = null
Firebase = null
//does not terminate here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question as: [How to destroy firebase ref in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641764/how-to-destroy-firebase-ref-in-node)

`Problem`: Firebase creates a long-live connection that prevents node to perminate.

`Solution`: to use `process.exit(0);` as a small hack to terminate node.

Also you can take a look at [Firebase API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/) docs, but seems they still haven't implemented `destroy()` or same method.

Comment: Except that if I have pending writes, as I do in my case, calling process.exit(0) will stop them being committed.

So I guess that makes a new question: "How do I know when pending writes have have been committed?"